# Can not convert UIView to UIImage on NewPad 9.3.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

use `- (nullable UIView *)resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates withCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)` to snapshot from a UIView which contain a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`,and then I want to convert the result(UIView *) to UIImage, and display that, but the UIImage is empty all the time.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 893);
UIView *photo = [self.cameraView resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(photo.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[photo drawViewHierarchyInRect:photo.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView * iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[iv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[self addSubview:iv];

CALayer * layer = [iv layer];
layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
layer.borderColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
```

Did anyone know why that can not get the right UIImage?

`Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
MacOS Sierra 10.12.3(16D32)
Deployment Target 9.3
iPad iOS 9.3.5`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the Objective-C-version of this, but try to convert it to Obj-C yourself, and add this code:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
photo.layer.render(in:context!)
```

Add it after

`[photo drawViewHierarchyInRect:photo.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];`

but before

`UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`

Comment: `[photo.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` does not work

Comment: @leezhm Hm.. I thought it would work.. Are you sure your UIView has been drawn? You send in `afterScreenUpdates:YES` in that draw-function, do you know what this code means? I don't.. Maybe it waits with drawing the view until the Screen is ready, but the rest of your code appens instantly. Try changing it to `NO`?

Comment: try to YES and NO, it does not work! My project is a iPad App, and I found this topic https://github.com/jfradj/ScreenshotIssue   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432222/drawviewhierarchyinrectafterscreenupdates-and-renderincontext-dont-work-ot

Answer (score -1):

Use the following method (untested):

```
- (UIImage *)renderViewToImage:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImage* image = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);          
    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];        
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();            
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

And call:

```
UIImage *img = [self renderViewToImage:photo]
```

You might want to make it an Category to `UIView`.

Comment: I do not have the chance to test in the moment. Try `view.bounds.size` instead of `view.frame.size`. And let us know what happens "does not work".

Comment: did not work! my project is a iPad App, and I found this https://github.com/jfradj/ScreenshotIssue